# stackoverflow when serializing hashmap in snakeyaml

Tags: java, stack-overflow, snakeyaml

i tried to serialize a class containing a hashmap with snakeYAML 1.13 and just got a pretty weird stackoverflow:

Full code has some other stuff in the class too which i stripped out for simplicity

example code used:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;


class TestClass
{
    public static void main(final String args2[])
    {
        IZSkinFile f = new IZSkinFile();
        HashMap<String,Point> ep = f.getElementPositions();
        ep.put("another unimportant name",new java.awt.Point(10, 10));
        System.out.println(new Yaml().dump(f));
    }
}

class IZSkinFile
{
    public IZSkinFile(String uprogram)
    {
        elementPositions = new HashMap<>();
    }
    public IZSkinFile(){
    elementPositions = new HashMap<>();    
    }//serialisierer....
    // private HashMap<String,String> elementDefinitions;//name>typ (Grafik/text/Schriftart)
    private HashMap<String,Point> elementPositions; //basisposition des elements
    public HashMap<String, Point> getElementPositions()
    {
        return elementPositions;
    }

    public void setElementPositions(HashMap<String, Point> elementPositions)
    {
        this.elementPositions = elementPositions;
    }
}
```

and the result is following Stackoverflow (only upper and lower end shown for saving unnecessary lines:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:122)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:415)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:132)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.Tag.<init>(Tag.java:87)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer.representJavaBean(Representer.java:74)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer$RepresentJavaBean.representData(Representer.java:49)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.BaseRepresenter.representData(BaseRepresenter.java:106)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer.representJavaBeanProperty(Representer.java:125)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer.representJavaBean(Representer.java:83)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer$RepresentJavaBean.representData(Representer.java:49)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.BaseRepresenter.representData(BaseRepresenter.java:106)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer.representJavaBeanProperty(Representer.java:125)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer.representJavaBean(Representer.java:83)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer$RepresentJavaBean.representData(Representer.java:49)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.BaseRepresenter.representData(BaseRepresenter.java:106)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer.representJavaBeanProperty(Representer.java:125)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer.representJavaBean(Representer.java:83)
...
...
...
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer.representJavaBeanProperty(Representer.java:125)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer.representJavaBean(Representer.java:83)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer$RepresentJavaBean.representData(Representer.java:49)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.BaseRepresenter.representData(BaseRepresenter.java:106)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer.representJavaBeanProperty(Representer.java:125)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer.representJavaBean(Representer.java:83)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer$RepresentJavaBean.representData(Representer.java:49)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.BaseRepresenter.representData(BaseRepresenter.java:106)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer.representJavaBeanProperty(Representer.java:125)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer.representJavaBean(Representer.java:83)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer$RepresentJavaBean.representData(Representer.java:49)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.BaseRepresenter.representData(BaseRepresenter.java:106)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the stupid issue...
somehow `java.awt.Point` messes up even though it only has 2 properties. using a `int[]` array with 2 ints now for storing due to the bug driving me crazy.

Comment: Great, accept your answer if the problem is fixed :)

Comment: need to wait 2 days until possible